# Organising a page tree using PHP foreach

Tags: php

I'm relatively inexperienced with PHP. Basically, I have some page data which looks like this:

[image: Data]

I'm looking to use `foreach` loops to organise child pages into a Subpages array, which will be a property of the parent page. Below is what I have written so far, which only has partial success. I was wondering if I'm along the right lines or if their is a much more efficient way of doing this using a library or a better logic. Any help would be appreciated!

PHP ($nav is the data is shown in the image about)

```
function renderNav($nav){

    $data = $nav;

    foreach ($data as &$page) {
        $page['Subpages'] = array_filter($data, function($i) use ($page){ return $i['ParentId'] == $page['Id']; });
        if(sizeof($page['Subpages'])==0){
            $page['Subpages'] = array();
        };
        usort($page['Subpages'], function($a, $b){ return $a['Order'] - $b['Order']; });
    };

    $filtered = array();
    foreach ($data as &$page) {
        if($page['ParentId'] == 0 || $page['ParentId'] == null){
            array_push($filtered, $page);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If I don't oversee something you can only 'render' two levels in hierarchie right now. I'd do this via a recursive function.

Comment: I'm looking to render an indeterminate number of levels if possible. Otherwise I can cap it at two sub-levels or something like that. I tried to do something recursive but my PHP is not great. Any insight would be appreciated :)

Comment: maybe start with some reading https://www.elated.com/articles/php-recursive-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't hold back and wrote a simple recursive function for that task:

```
<?php
// demo input
$nav = [array("id"=>21, "parentId"=>20, "Order"=>0),
        array("id"=>20, "parentId"=>17, "Order"=>0),
        array("id"=>18, "parentId"=>17, "Order"=>1),
        array("id"=>19, "parentId"=>18, "Order"=>0),
        array("id"=>17, "parentId"=>0, "Order"=>0),
        array("id"=>16, "parentId"=>18, "Order"=>1)


       ];

// the actual recursive function
function walkNav($a, $parentId=0) {
    $parents = array_values(array_filter($a, function($sub) use($parentId) { return $sub['parentId'] == $parentId; }));
    foreach($parents as &$parent) {
        $parent['children'] = walkNav($a, $parent['id']);   
    }
    return $parents;
}

// usage
$result = walkNav($nav);

// output
echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($result);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "</pre>";
```

You can now use that array (`$result`) to build your nav!
This function would get quite expensive when the input gets bigger. I refrained from doing optimisation here (unsetting used items in recursion), because there won't be 1000 items in your case.

Here's the result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 17,
        "parentId": 0,
        "Order": 0,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 20,
                "parentId": 17,
                "Order": 0,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "parentId": 20,
                        "Order": 0,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "parentId": 17,
                "Order": 1,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "parentId": 18,
                        "Order": 0,
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "parentId": 18,
                        "Order": 1,
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```